# Getting "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, javac

I get the message

> " Example.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>    Scanner finput = new Scanner(filed);
>                                   ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   variable filed
>
> location: class Example "

When I complile my program. I've tried looking this up but I can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Here is the code

```
public class Example
{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
     java.io.File filer = new java.io.File("RESULT.txt");
     System.out.println("Choose the location of the data file");
     JFileChooser fileCh = new JFileChooser();
     if (fileCh.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        java.io.File filed = fileCh.getSelectedFile();
     }
     else {
         System.out.println ("No file choosen.");
         System.exit(1);

 }
     Scanner finput = new Scanner(filed);
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a typo, use this: `Scanner finput = new Scanner(filer)` ... you used `new Scanner(filed)`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How do you know it's a typo? It could have been meant for the `filed` declared inside the `if` block. Of course, that doesn't make any sense, but neither does have to closely named `File` variables, so who knows for sure what OP intended.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, you could be right, in which he should just declare the `File` outside the `if` statement.  Still could be argued to be a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has already been mentioned you need to move the declaration of the `filed` variable outside of the if statement. Your code can be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    java.io.File filer = new java.io.File("RESULT.txt");
    System.out.println("Choose the location of the data file");
    JFileChooser fileCh = new JFileChooser();
    java.io.File filed = null;

    if (fileCh.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        filed = fileCh.getSelectedFile();
    } else {
        System.out.println("No file choosen.");
        System.exit(1);

    }
    Scanner finput = new Scanner(filed);
}
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving this error because `filed` is being accessed from an illegal scope. Try defining `java.io.File filed` outside of the if statement. Or maybe you wanted to use `Scanner finput = new Scanner(filer)`?

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions, just vote to close them :-)